# Calculating difference between 2 items in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have some customer data in an array of javascript objects that looks as such:

```
  const clientData = [
    {
      client: 'Pizza Hutt',
      food_cost: 400.00,
      prev_year_food_cost: 450.00,
    },
    {
      client: 'Pizza World',
      food_cost: 500.00,
      prev_year_food_cost: 650.00,
    },
  ];
```

I would like to loop over and get the difference between `food_cost` and `prev_year_food_cost` for each client. So ideally, I would have a new object containing `client`, `food_cost` and the difference.

```
[
    {
      client: 'Pizza Hutt',
      food_cost: 400.00,
      difference: 50.00,
    },
    {
      client: 'Pizza World',
      food_cost: 500.00,
      difference: 150.00,
    },
];
```

I have tried this but its not quite right. It's pseudo code.

```
const comparisonData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      const item = { ...data[i] };
      // console.log(item);
      Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
        if (key !== 'campaignname' && !key.includes(comparisonPeriodData.excluded_period)) {
             Do calculations here
          }
        }
      });
      push data onto comparisonData
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` to apply the transformation over each object, using `Math.abs` to find the absolute difference.

We can use destructuring to remove the `prev_year_food_cost` from the object.

This can be made more configurable by using the bracket syntax:

```js
let clientData = [{ client: 'Pizza Hutt', food_cost: 400.00, prev_year_food_cost: 450.00, }, { client: 'Pizza World', food_cost: 500.00, prev_year_food_cost: 650.00, }];

const difference = (arr, key) => {
  return arr.map(o => {
    const { ["prev_year_" + key]: prev, ...rest} = o;
    return { ...rest,
       difference: Math.abs(o["prev_year_" + key] - o[key])
    }
  });
}
console.log(difference(clientData, "food_cost"));

clientData = [{ client: 'Pizza Hutt', water_cost: 400.00, prev_year_water_cost: 450.00, }, { client: 'Pizza World', water_cost: 500.00, prev_year_water_cost: 650.00, }];

console.log(difference(clientData, "water_cost"));
```

Comment: Would this be possible with more metrics? This is exactly what I want, but let's say we had something like water_cost and prev_year_water_cost?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the name of the key as an argument

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.map()` method. `Array.prototype.map()` method call the provided callback function for each item of the array and generates a new array as a result. Traverse the array using map method and get the difference between `food_cost` and `prev_year_food_cost` for each client and use `Math.abs()` for absolute value.

```js
const clientData = [
  {
    client: "Pizza Hutt",
    food_cost: 400.0,
    prev_year_food_cost: 450.0,
  },
  {
    client: "Pizza World",
    food_cost: 500.0,
    prev_year_food_cost: 650.0,
  },
];

const ret = clientData.map(({ client, food_cost, prev_year_food_cost }) => ({
  client,
  food_cost,
  difference: Math.abs(food_cost - prev_year_food_cost),
}));
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const clientData = [
    {
      client: 'Pizza Hutt',
      food_cost: 400.00,
      prev_year_food_cost: 450.00,
    },
    {
      client: 'Pizza World',
      food_cost: 500.00,
      prev_year_food_cost: 650.00,
    }
  ];
  
  const updated = clientData.map(item => {
    item.difference = Math.abs(item.food_cost - item.prev_year_food_cost);
    delete item.prev_year_food_cost;
    return item;
  });
  
  console.log(updated);
```